# How to use linked list to store a table and search for items in the table in C++

Tags: c++, search, linked-list

I have a .txt file saved on a local drive that consists of 3 columns and numerous rows, with the first column being characters, second column being numbers, third column being dates. How can I write a program using **linked list** (without using STL) to store this file and then be able to search for a specific entry by letting the user enter information from the first column, so that the computer will find it from the table and display the information in that row?

Comment: ¤ Presumably the main point of this exercise is to implement a linked list yourself. Then *make it simple*: a singly linked list with no embellishments. Since C++ supports reference arguments you can simplify things tremendously by defining a function `Node* unlink( Node*& p )`, which you can then call with the `next` pointer of a node as argument. And also, a function `void linkInAfter( Node& node, Node* p )`. All of which implies that you need to define a type called `Node`. Note a linked list is very far from an ideal structure for the given problem, but as homework it's ok. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to do this would be to use a structure like this:

```
struct Row
{
    char * name;
    int    id;
    time_t date;

    Row * next;
};
Row * table = NULL;
```

This structure would store one row of your .txt file and a pointer to the next row. This makes it a linked list. The `table` variable would point to the head of the list — the first row.

To store the list, you would go through the table and write each row to a new line with `fprintf`.

```
for (Row * row = table; row != NULL; row = row->next)
    fprintf(file, "%s %i %i", row->name, row->id, row->date);
```

To search through the list, you would iterate through the table and compare the target string with the `name` member of each row (or whatever you call it). With a linked list you are, pretty much, limited to sequential search.

```
for (Row * row = table; row != NULL; row = row->next)
    if (0 == stcmp(row->name, targetString))
        return row;
```

I presume that you covered user input and basic list algorithms in class. Feel free to ask, if you have any problems.

Comment: Thanks so much! Could you explain a little bit what exactly this code does, though? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can review the following concepts in c++ and then tackle your problem

1. [File Handling](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)
2. [Linked Lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) : This wikipedia entry and its external links would help you learn the basic operations on linked lists.
3. Searching: You can implement a searching algorithm of your choice to find the required info. Basic search algorithm like linear search  would suffice.
   Integrate these concepts and solve your problem!

You can use Don Reba's structure to implement the nodes of the linked list

Comment: Can't use binary search on a list.

Comment: @DonReba Oh yeah the list has to be sorted.. I've edited my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @DonReba Learnt about problem in binary search on linked lists in http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~holte/T26/binary-search.html I've edited my answer. Thanks!